# Create a pydantic model with dynamic keys

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to create a Pydantic model for this structure:

```json
{
  "key-1": ["value-1", "value-2"],
  "key-2": ["value-3"],
  "key-3": []
}
```

My first attempt was

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
  __root__ = Dict[str, List[str]]

  @root_validator(pre=True)
  def validate_all_the_things(cls, values):
    # check if keys and values match some regexes
```

But this raises an exception:

```
RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'typing._GenericAlias'>, see `arbitrary_types_allowed` in Config
```

If i change `Dict` to `dict`, i don’t get the exception, but the resulting object yields an empty dict:

```
>>> MyModel(**{"key-1": ["value-1"]}).dict()
{}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i make a key dynamic in a pydantic model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261606/how-can-i-make-a-key-dynamic-in-a-pydantic-model)

Comment: I saw this, but it doesn't help (it throws the above exception). Even if i use `dict` instead of `Dict`, it still yields an empy dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in model declaration. Use a colon instead of the equal sign.

```
from typing import List, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, List[str]]
```

Then you can create a model instance:

```
>>> my_instance = MyModel.parse_obj({"key-1": ["value-1"]})
>>> my_instance.dict()
{'__root__': {'key-1': ['value-1']}}
```

You can find more information here: [custom-root-types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types)

Please also look at this section. Maybe you will find here some interesting stuff: [dynamic-model-creation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation)